# How to increase value of a k consecutive elements in an vector in c++?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have an vector in c++ of size 8 with elements {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1} and i want to increase the size of a specific portion of vector by one, for example, lets say the portion of vector which needs to be increase by 1 is 0 to 5, then our final result is {1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}.

Is it possible to do this in constant time using standard method of vectors (like we a memset in c), without running any loop?

Comment: Memset isn't a constant time operation.

Comment: You need to loop through the segment which needs to be updated. Or you may try different data structures like `Segment Tree With Lazy Propagation`.  Your updations will be constant but retrievals will be log(N).

Comment: yeah @sameerkn atleast it is better than running a loop through whole segment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No... and by the way with `memset` you don't have a guaranteed constant-time operation either (in most implementation is just very fast but still linear in the number of elements).

If you need to do this kind of operation (addition/subtraction of a constant over a range) on a very huge vector a lot of times and you need to get the final result then you can get O(1) per update using a different algorithm:

#### Step 1: convert the data to its "derivative"

This mean replacing each element with the difference from previous one.

```
// O(n) on the size of the vector, but done only once
for (int n=v.size()-1; i>0; i--) {
    v[i] -= v[i-1];
}
```

#### Step 2: do all the interval operations (each in constant time)

With this representation adding a constant to a range simply means adding it to the first element and subtracting it from the element past the ending one. In code:

```
// intervals contains structures with start/stop/value fields
// Operation is O(n) on the **number of intervals**, and does
// not depend on the size of them
for (auto r : intervals) {
    v[r.start] += r.value;
    v[r.stop+1] -= r.value;
}
```

#### Step 3: Collect the results

Finally you just need to un-do the initial processing, getting back to the normal values on each cell by integrating. In code:

```
// O(n) on the size of vector, but done only once
for (int i=1,n=v.size(); i<n; i++) {
    v[i] += v[i-1];
}
```

Note that both step 1 and 3 (derivation and integration) can be done in parallel on N cores with perfect efficiency if the size is large enough, even if how this is possible may be not obvious at a first sight (it wasn't for me, at least).

Comment: In "Step 3: Collect the results"  it should be `for (int i=1,n=v.size(); i<n; i++)`. `i ` should start from 1.

Comment: @6502 thanks i reduced my code running time from 1.89s to 0.37s